# What can I use as a substitute for canned refrigerated biscuits in monkey bread?

Tags: substitutions, biscuits

I'm making monkey bread and I need refrigerated biscuits. I don't have any, however, and I don't really want to go buy them. What could I use instead of refrigerated biscuits?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I know you've been around the network a bit, so we're glad you stopped in here. I'm glad your monkey bread worked out, and hope you'll be back with more questions/answers about cooking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using refrigerated biscuits for [monkey bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_bread) is actually just a convenient shortcut - if you don't have pre-prepared biscuit dough at hand, you can simply *make your own sweet yeast dough from scratch*, that's the classic (pre-Pillsbury-can) recipe.

Either find a recipe that uses sweet yeast dough from scratch or substitute your favourite sweet yeast dough. (The Wikipedia page linked above has a link to a recipe, for example.)

Comment: Canned biscuits aren't a yeast dough, this makes Your answer is a bit confusing.

Comment: @DebbieM. I know, but the classic recipe is made with sweet yeast dough, hence a reasonable substitute. I'll clarify.